# Android WebView: Using relative paths when loading javascript from assets

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, webview

I was able to create an Android hello world app that loads html file from assets folder using WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL method:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/appcode/", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

My html looks somewhat like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>

    <script src="/js/lib/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script> <!-- This script is not being loaded -->
    <script src="helloWorld.js"></script> <!-- This script is being loaded -->

</head>
<body>
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is the following: jquery-1.11.0.js is not being loaded while helloWorld.js file loads successfully. I verified that the file exists under relative path.

If I move jquery-1.11.0.js to the html file location (to the same place where helloWorld.js is located), it fixes the problem. But I want to use relative paths for loading scripts. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

1. Moving all js files under /assets/appcode/ is not an option,
   because I am planning to reuse html files that are relying on these
   relative paths
2. Using CDN links will not work, because I'm
   planning to load my own scripts that are not available on the web
3. If i use "file:///android_asset/appcode/js/lib/jquery-1.11.0.js" instead of "/js/lib/jquery-1.11.0.js" it also works. But this is absolute path, when I want to use relative.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use CDN instead:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="helloWorld.js"></script>
```

Comment: That will fix only the problem with jquery. I have my own javascript files under /js/lib/ folder that I can't load from the web.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute paths sometimes don't work in the WebView such as JavaScript file.
I suggest use relative path with dot(.) followed with path

```
<script src="./js/lib/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
             ^
```

Answer (score 0):

To use absolute path do this, for example:

Instead of calling your JS file like this:

```html
<script src="/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Do like this:

```html
<script src="file:///android_asset/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also all my web files are located in the following android project folder: \app\src\main\assets